# Upgrading to Rails 4 from Rails 3 gotchas

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-4, upgrade

We have an app in Rails 3.2 that we want to upgrade to Rails 4.0. I have read the various guidelines available on the possible issues like [here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html) and [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/415-upgrading-to-rails-4?view=asciicast).

I would like to know of some not so common/obvious gotchas that we should be aware of when upgrading to 4.0?

Answer (score 2):

Ones that got me:

- CanCan not yet playing nicely with StrongParameters: Ended up using [this work-around](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/issues/835#issuecomment-21321676).
- Named Scopes require Procs: Well documented, but still got me. See my [issue here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18912306/best-way-to-test-named-scopes-in-rails4).
- Turbolinks bypasses document.ready: [Good overview here.](http://staal.io/blog/2013/01/18/dangers-of-turbolinks/)